# Huawei S9706 FIB/RIB Size

Tags: huawei

I searched a lot on internet but could not find how much is route table size for the following Huawei configuration :

```
EH1D2SRUDC00 Main Control Unit
2x EH1D2X16SFC0 16-Port 10GBASE-X Interface Card (FC, SFP+)
EH1D2S24CSA0 24-Port 100/1000BASE-X and 8-Port 10/100/1000BASE-T Combo
Interface Card (SA, SFP/RJ45)
LE02CMUA Centralized Monitoring Board
2x W2PSA2230 Power Supply 2247W
2x Fan Modules
```

Can i have 4-5x BGP Full table on this switch?